# why i get invalid integer exception each time i click my button?

Tags: android

I have is an android class. I get some data from get extra which are displayed fine. All of the data is strings. Here is my class:

```
package adapter;

public class AddToCart extends Activity {

  EditText quantity=null;
  TextView total=null;
  TextView name=null;
  TextView price=null;
  TextView ava=null;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.info);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String itemprice = intent.getStringExtra("price");
    String itemname = intent.getStringExtra("item");
    final String itemava = intent.getStringExtra("ava");
    int imagehandler = intent.getIntExtra("image", 0);

    Log.e("image handler",imagehandler+"");
    name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    price = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    total = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    ava = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    quantity = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button addtocart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ImageView imageview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    name.setText(itemname);
    price.setText(itemprice);
    ava.setText(itemava);
    imageview.setImageResource(imagehandler);

    addtocart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      int currentava = Integer.parseInt(itemava);
      @Override

      public void onClick(View v) {
        try{
          String checked = quantity.getText().toString();
          if(checked==null) {
            Toast.makeText(AddToCart.this,"please enter quantity for your item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
          else {
            int x=0;
            double y=0.0;

            x = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString());
            y = Double.parseDouble(itemprice);
            Log.e("x",x+"");
            Log.e("y",y+"");
            double totalprice=x*y;
            total.setText(totalprice+"");
            Toast.makeText(AddToCart.this,"your item added succesfully !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
        }//view
        catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

As you can see that quantity is edit text and when some number inserted into it multiply it by price value and show the total price in text view which works just fine when i click the button, but what I really need to do is to handle this functionality with two if statements. First if the edit text for quantity was empty and the user click the button I want a toast to be displayed to says : "please enter a value for quantity" and the other statement that if quantity larger than available to refuse the value and also toast : "please enter value less than available" It doesn't work as I have an invalid integer value exception. Please what is wrong with my code and how can i handle the previous issues?

Answer (score 0):

Declare "itemava" globally and try again

Answer (score 0):

Text can still be empty... Try something like this:

```
import android.text.TextUtils;

String value = quantity.getText().toString();
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
    // enter a value toast
} else if (!TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(value)) {
    // must be numeric toast (notice the exclamation mark in condition)
} else {
    int valueInt = Integer.parseInt(value);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: what is TextUtils? can you explain more please?

Comment: It's part of the Android API as a helper class to everyday simple string validation checks and more, check out the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me where you use ,

```
 if(checked==null){
                    Toast.makeText(AddToCart.this,"please enter quantity for your item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

that there are 2 alternatives to this.

## 1.

#### Probably the easiest

```
if(checked==null || quantity.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(AddToCart.this,"please enter quantity for your item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

The addition is the `|| quantitiy.isEmpty()`
I had tons of issues trying to solve for cases when the string was empty and this is the best way and also uses built in functions that are very easy to use.

## 2.

#### Not quite as easy but probably the better bet

Rather than checking to see if the string itself is null, it would be best to check if the `editText` has been changed at all, and then if it has been changed, make sure that it was changed to a non-empty string, like in **1.** To do this add a `textChangedListener` like so:

```
    quantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //set a textChangedFlag to true
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

This will require a boolean flag that should **always** be initialized to false. Then after setting the flag to true in the onTextChanged method, you should still double check the string, just to be safe (this may be overkill, but I tend to error on the side of caution) by using a similar method as in **1.**

```
if(textChangedFlag && !(checked == NULL || quantity.isEmpty())){
     //do your math here
}
else{
     Toast.makeText(AddToCart.this,"please enter a valid quantity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```